# anaconda install python 3.4 on windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I want to install and use python 3.4 and its numerous libraries, (such as numpy, pandas, etc) using Anaconda.  Unfortunately, I am unable to activate python 3.4.

I installed Acaconda 2.0 (Anaconda-2.0.0-Windows-x86_64) on a Windows 8 notebook.  The Anaconda program installed properly and python 2.7 was installed.  I then attempted to install python 3.4 using these commands at a command prompt in the C:\Program Files\Anaconda directory.

```
$ conda update conda
$ conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
$ activate py34
```

The first two seemed to work fine as I saw no error messages. At the last step I receive the following error message:  `No environment named “py34” exits in C:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs`

Python 3.4 was installed not in the C:\Program Files\Anaconda but in the C:\Users\Daddio1949\envs\py34 directory.

I not sure how to proceed to finalize the installation, what should I do?

Comment: Think I was having the same problem. I started from scratch and it's working. Deleted Anaconda and all versions of Python. Removed python from my "Environemt Variables" PATH. Then re-installed just anaconda python 2.7, then used the same commands as you from /Anaconda/envs>

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda uses relative paths to locate the `envs` folder. Whenever you run the `anaconda.bat` or the `activate.bat` script, the script looks for its own location, e.g. `C:\someplace\Scripts\activate.bat`, then looks for an `..\envs` folder, e.g. `C:\someplace\envs`.

What you are describing here sounds to me like you are having multiple folders with the `*.bat` scripts in your `%PATH%` variable (likely because you haven't writing rights for the `C:\Program Files\Anaconda` folder).
When running `activate.bat` it seems to come from your `C:\Program Files` folder, whereas `conda` seems to run from your `C:\Users` directory.

My suggestions:

- Try to run the `*.bat` scripts from your `C:\Users\Daddio1949\Scripts` directory (if present). If it does not exist, copy `activate.bat` and `deactivate.bat` from the Anaconda `Scripts` directory to your user scripts directory and run the `*.bat` files from there.
- Try to find out if you have other `activate.bat` in your Windows `%PATH%` folders. Make sure that you call the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `activate` script on Windows does not support activating environments not in the standard `envs` directory currently. Until this is fixed, you'll need to just modify the `PATH` variable manually.